# how server can interrupt client program?

Tags: network-programming

how server program can interrupt the client program?
client and server are in different machines.
server want to send a file to all clients every time the file is changed.
can server send signal to client?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear in requirements but roughly you can follow this approach that all the clients should listen on some port for new files and whenever server has got new file it can send on that port. Preferably the client should have multi threaded architecture so that the client is listening for new file in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. You don't even say which technologies you're interested in (Microsoft vs. Unix, for instance).

In general, the clients should *ask* the server to be notified. That way, the service can know who the clients are and can determine if they are authorized to receive the notifications. The clients then listen on a port that the server knows to send on, and the server can send them a notification. Perhaps the request from the client tells the server which port to send on.

Answer (score 0):

Does the client has an persistent connection with the server or is a connection only set up if there is data to be transferred? In the latter, you have to set up something like Raza described. But in case of an persistent connection, you could set up some sort of multiplexing technique on the client-server connection. For example something like:

```
S:0[DATA]
C:0[DATA]
S:1[GotFile]
C:1[GimmeFile]  *
S:0[DATA]
S:1[File]  *
C:0[DATA]
C:1[Thanks] *
S:0[DATA]
```

One last thing, you could setup an broadcast or multicast solution in which you send the file to every listening client. However it is hard to do so securely thus in a way that the file is encrypted by the server and decrypted by the client. Moreover you have to ensure the integrity of the file.